# How to exclude time value from a date value?

Tags: date, datetime, time, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have an excel file connected to a form and a gallery in my power app. I also have an add button which adds values as seen in the screenshot.

[image]

The problem is that it includes the time in the excel file. And somehow the date gets reduced by one day and gets the `(selected date-1)` day and the `22:00` or `00:00`.

[image]

Does anybody know how to fix that?

I tried this:
[image]
The time is still included as you can see...

Answer (score 1):

Since your picture shows German text, I assume the cause of the issue is that your app and your Excel datasource are interpreting time differently (your CET time was converted into UTC).

I recommend you watch [this video from Shane](https://youtu.be/dbsc-Mvh7Co?t=1020) where explains how PowerApps works with Excel and what you can do to counter this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, I looked at the settings of our sharepoint site and the time is set to  UTC... I dont know what to do now.

Comment: sry it is UTC+1

Comment: You could try converting timezones in your PowerApps formula, as instructed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/power-fx/reference/function-dateadd-datediff#converting-to-utc

Comment: But the main problem remains that the date can not be stored in excel without the time. But thank you for your help.